# Class hierarchy using UML

Tags: java, file, uml

The task is to create class/interface hierarchy using this simple diagram [Diagram](http://cs605624.vk.me/v605624202/42a4/HIrYsUnIfKc.jpg). Can somebody check my attempt to do it, and say what i doing wrong. I need the class SystemFile to be able to keep the array of my IFile objects depends on the currentDirectory value. Classes that realize IFile interface need to do some of FIle class methods as File class does. another problem is in listFiles method, it returns File value, how can i make it IFile?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.cert.Extension;

public interface IFile {
public String getName();

public String getParent();

public String getPath();

public String getAbsolutePath();

public long lastModified();

public boolean isFile();

public boolean isDirectory();

public long size();

public boolean exists();

public boolean delete();

public File[] listFiles();

public InputStream getInputStream();

public OutputStream getOutputStream();

public Extension getFileExtension();

}
 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
 import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

 public class FileSystemTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements
    Constants {

private IFile currentDirectory;
private IFile[] files;


@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 3;  
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return files.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {

    switch (arg1) {
    case 0:
        if(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().isDrive((IFile)files[arg0]))
        return files[arg0].toString();
        else
            return files[arg0].getName();
    case 1:
        return files[arg0].size();
    case 2:
        return new Date(files[arg0].lastModified());
    }
    return arg1;    
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public IFile getCurrentDirectory() {
    return currentDirectory;
}

public void setCurrentDirectory(IFile currentDirectory) {
    this.currentDirectory = currentDirectory;
}

public void setFiles(IFile[] files) {
    this.files = files;
}

public IFile[] getFiles() {
    return files;
}


@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    switch(column){
    case 0:
        return TABLE_COLUMN_NAME;
    case 1:
        return TABLE_COLUMN_SIZE;
    case 2:
        return TABLE_COLUMN_MODIFIED;
    } 

    return null;
}
 }
 public class SystemFile extends File implements IFile {


 public SystemFile(String arg0) {
    super(arg0);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

 @Override
 public String getName() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return super.getName();
}

@Override
public String getParent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getParent();
}

@Override
public String getPath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getPath();
}

@Override
public String getAbsolutePath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getAbsolutePath();
}

@Override
public long lastModified() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.lastModified();
}

@Override
public boolean isFile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.isFile();
}

@Override
public boolean isDirectory() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.isDirectory();
}

public long size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.length();
}

@Override
public boolean exists() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.exists();
}

@Override
public boolean delete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.delete();
}

@Override
public File[] listFiles() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.listFiles();
}

@Override
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Extension getFileExtension() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

 }
```

I'm not using remotefile class yet.

Comment: Is it your homework ?

Comment: its just a little part